# How do I add external files to a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, dll, lib

I'm working with Jenkins to make a build of a Visual Studio C++ project I have in a git repository. However, although I don't upload them to github, my project needs SDL2's external libraries and DLL as well as some assets.

How can I add them to my jenkins job to generate a build of my project? I want to add the SDL2's libs and DLL as well as my assets folder and place them in the job workspace, in a way that won't make me upload the files everytime jenkins builds my project. But I haven't found anything that clears that for me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If your project needs assets (something like pixel art), this should probably be uploaded to GitHub along with your code. Another option is to uploaded assets to some other public/private repository that Jenkins can access.

As for the SDL2 libraries and DLL, you are correct that this should not be uploaded to GitHub. Instead, I would recommend using something like Docker to package your C++ project with its dependencies. Manually installing them on the Jenkins server is also an option, but not ideal because you'll have to do this on any machine you want your code to run.

Hope that gives you somewhere to start!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into it and see if I can manage :)